# Generate HTML from XML using only XSD and no XSL

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, xsd

I'm new to development, apologies and thanks in advance.
I have a case where within my XML and XSD files I have :

xml :

```
<paragraph>
  My
    <a href="www.google.co.nz">Googlefoo</a>
  is not strong.
</paragraph>
```

xsd :

```
<xsd:element name="paragraph">
  <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="a"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="a">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="href" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Also a DTD wich may be of use.

```
<!ELEMENT paragraph        (#PCDATA | a )*>
<!ELEMENT a    (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST a href CDATA  #REQUIRED>
```

These files are hosted offsite, I have no control over them. They are used for site content generation. I can get the elements and attributes out via PHP and splice them together so its ok with the data as it stands. However is there a way to apply the XSD onto the XML so that the output is as is, ie : mixed content that when pulled out looks all HTML happy like.

I believe that .XSD only is really used to define the format of the data that you can validate against, or that may be wrong.

I do not have a .XSL which, as far as I know, XSLT transformation would need and could do this for me. This is ideally what I would like to do if somehow achievable.

Not sure if I could somehow apply CData to the element and then parse it.
I haven't found a way to generate a xsl on the fly.

Any guidance or a pointer to a resource would be great. Long live the Rubber Ducky.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. You _can_ apply an *.xsd (an XML Schema) to an XML document, then, this process is called **validation**. Is this what you'd like to do? Or do you generate HTML? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm new to development*

That's ok, we all started somewhere. From reading your post it seems that you are mixing technologies and aren't sure which is which.

> *Also a DTD wich may be of use.*
>   *[...]They are used for site content generation*

Your DTD, and also the XSD, are used for *validation* of the XML. For this you need [a validating XML parser](http://webdesign.about.com/od/parsers/a/validating-and-non-validating-parsers.htm) (for the DTD) or and [XSD processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29). These are *not* used for content generation, at best the schemas are used to *validate* whether the generated content is correct according to the contract in the schema. I.e., whether an element can have child elements or only textual content.

> *I believe that .XSD only is really used to define the format of the data that you can validate against, or that may be wrong.*

This is correct.

> *[...] so that the output is as is, ie : mixed content that when pulled out looks all HTML happy like.*
>   *[...] I do not have a .XSL which, as far as I know, XSLT transformation would need and could do this for me. This is ideally what I would like
>   to do if somehow achievable.*

Depending on what you want to achieve, XSLT might be a way to go. It really depends on the content management system you are using, this is for a desktop application or a webapp, whether it must run serverside or client side whether this is feasible in your situation. If you [Google for "xslt php introduction"](https://www.google.com/search?q=xslt%20introduction%20php) you will find such tutorials [like this one](http://devzone.zend.com/179/using-php-and-xsl-to-transform-xml-into-web-content/) about generating content for the web.

To generate "HTML happy" XML, you will need to specify what elements have to be translated into what HTML elements. I.e., your `paragraph` can be translated into `p` and your `a`-element can remain as is. For these kinds of tasks, XSLT is a good choice. But again, it depends on your infrastructure whether this is feasible or not.

The natural way of using XSLT for the job is typically to process your input XML server side, this then goes in this order: get input XML -> validate XML with XSD processor -> run XML as input against XSLT stylesheet -> grab the output of this transformation -> serve this output to the end user (i.e., a web page, web app, desktop app).

Comment: Thanks for your time. Appreciate the feedback and I'll look into those tutorials. But basically the missing ingredient here for me would be the xslt style sheet. Have a good day :).

Comment: @fable XSLT is a programming language, you can do anything with it. It highly depends on your input XML and your requested output how it has to be coded up. There are many tutorials and even free books online, but if you get stuck, feel free to ask a new question on SO :)